# iOS Haptic Touch API Possibilities

Tags: ios, xcode, uitouch, 3dtouch, haptic-feedback

Since we are losing 3D Touch API's with iOS 13, such as `UIViewControllerPreviewing`, `UIContextMenuInteraction` seems to be the replacement.

UIContextMenuInteraction is good if you want to put up a menu upon Haptic Touch.  What if you want to do something else at the recognition of Haptic Touch?

Is there such a thing? Or is Haptic Touch is same as `UILongPressGesture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation UIContextMenuInteraction inherits from UIInteraction. Searching for all subclasses:

- UIContextMenuInteraction
- UIDragInteraction
- UIDropInteraction
- **UILargeContentViewerInteraction**
- UIPencilInteraction
- UISpringLoadedInteraction
- UITextInteraction

Reviewing each subclass I think that the one that best suits to replace UIViewControllerPreviewing is UILargeContentViewerInteraction because UILargeContentViewerInteractionDelegate has a method to return a view controller.

[UIViewControllerPreviewing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollerpreviewing)

[UIContextMenuInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction)

[UIInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinteraction)

[UILargeContentViewerInteractionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilargecontentviewerinteractiondelegate)

Comment: When using UILargeContentViewerInteraction, would the view controller be interactive?

Comment: I did not a test so I don't know the limitations, but I think that any view controller is valid.

Answer (score 1):

UIContextMenuInteraction is an exact replacement. You don't have to put up a menu; you can put up just a custom preview. And that preview is a snapshot of a view controller's view, and you provide that view controller. And the user can then tap the preview to perform an actual view controller transition. So this is the exact analog of peek-and-pop with view controllers.